# Finding a magento method definition, specifically getOptionList()

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have been re-purposing Magento's wishlist module into my own version of it, and have been mostly successful in re-tracing how each part of it is put together.

In **app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/wishlist/options_list.phtml** is how the wishlist displays product options and configurations. It calls `$this->getOptionList()` which returns an array of the options/configuration associated with that product. I had trouble tracing where this method comes from, so I searched the entire **app/code/core/** directory, which turned up nothing related to the wishlist!

Where does this method come from? I would like to use it elsewhere within the wishlist module, but it appears to be exclusive to that particular class, yet its not defined anywhere so I'm completely confused.

Magento 1.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: `setOptionList` is called via a magic method, which makes a property called `option_list`. This can be retrieved via `getOptionList` later.

*First, let's start at the template:*

Template file options_list.phtml uses the `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Options` block class. That class extends `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Abstract`, which extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`.  That class file, in turn, extends `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`, which is ultimately a subclass of `Varien_Object`.

None of these classes have a property or method named `options_list`, either. So where does it come from?

**This is part of Magento's ORM** that provides **magic getters and setters** for some data in objects. Properties on objects are separated via underscores and many times correlate to database table column names. Many objects relate back to database tables directly. For instance, `base_tax_amount` in sales_flat_order is called via `getBaseTaxAmount()`.

How does `option_list` get populated, though? Simple. In `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist` on line 178:

```
    return $block->setTemplate($template)
        ->setOptionList($helper->getOptions($item))
        ->toHtml();
```

This behavior is achieved via `__call`, a built-in functionality in PHP that allows you to route method calls when they reference a non-existant class method:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

**What now? I need to extend this!**

Good news, you can. Extend or rewrite the `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Options` class as per usual and add in the following method:

```
public function getOptionList()
{
  $options = parent::getOptionList();
  //your functionality here
  return $options;
}
```

Your new method will be found when invoked via the option_list.phtml template, and your method will reference the parent - which as we know doesn't exist. That will fall back to `__call`, which will return the `option_list` property on your object. **Don't forget to return `$options`** at the end!

*Additional Reading:*

This may be helpful to you to understand the Varien Object system at Magento's core:

http://alanstorm.com/magento_varien_object_debugging

Comment: Wow, if I could buy you a drink. When I was researching this, magic methods did come up but I had trouble grasping how they worked in general, let alone in Magento. So, I thank you for an answer that I somehow understood ;p

I do have one follow-up question though: I'm trying to call getOptionList from a custom module that extends `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Abstract`. Would it work in there, since it all traces back to the Varien Object anyway?

Comment: It may not work since the `setOptionList` is happening in the context of `$block`, which is not the Abstract, but the concrete class. If you can rewrite `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Options`, you should have access to it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, your answer actually showed me I was barking up the wrong tree.